# What is the lookup time complexity of Consistent Hashing Design?

Tags: hash, architecture, time-complexity, consistent-hashing

While reading Alex Xu's book on designing large systems, I had a question about the part about consistent hashing.

The book says that in a stable hash, the server where the key will be stored is a linear search in a clockwise direction, looking for the first server it encounters.

If so, **I'm wondering if there is a time complexity penalty for searching than the hashing method using modulo.** (modulo means. general hashing)

Comment: Do you mean `modulo`?

Comment: @user207421 oh yes, modulo haha..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at [this diagram](https://twitter.com/alexxubyte/status/1554851915069943813) which depicts how the consistent hashing based lookup works.

[image: consistent hashing]

### The hash ring

- you have hash ring which represents the entire hash internal

  - the beginning and the end of the interval is interconnected
- you try to place your servers on the ring by having identical spaces between them

  - that's the initial state, whenever you add/remove a server the distances between them might not be the same (example: `s4`)

### Lookup

- You calculate the hash for a given key
- You locate the hashed key on the hash ring
- You try to find the nearest server node by moving toward clockwise

In the above example we wanted to place `key0` on to the `server 0`. But due to a server failure it has been removed the cluster. A new server `server 4` has been added to cluster to replace `server 0`. Because `s4` has been placed between `s3` and `s1` nodes that's why that's the closest server node clockwise to the `k0` hash.

### Time complexity

To better understand consistent hashing I highly recommend to you to read this excellent article: http://highscalability.com/blog/2023/2/22/consistent-hashing-algorithm.html

Please allow me to quote here the time complexity table for binary-search-tree

| Operation | Time Complexity | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Add a node | `O(k/n + logn)` | `O(k/n)` for redistribution of keys `O(logn)` for binary search tree traversal |
| Remove a node | `O(k/n + logn)` | `O(k/n)` for redistribution of keys `O(logn)` for binary search tree traversal |
| Add a key | `O(logn)` | `O(logn)` for binary search tree traversal |
| Remove a key | `O(logn)` | `O(logn)` for binary search tree traversal |

where `k` = total number of keys, `n` = total number of nodes [2, 7].

Comment: good reference! thx :)